# How to split the single cell CITESeq data based on Hashtag antibody?

Tags: rna-seq, seurat, scanpy

I am trying to analyze single cell CITESeq data from 10x. My data contains total 6 Hashtag antibody. Hashtag 1,2 and 3 were used for WT and Hashtag 4,5, and 6 were used for KO library preparation. We ran all the library together. Now I need to split the data into two groups. WT group should contain Hashtag 1,2 and 3. KO group should contain Hashtag 4,5 and 6. Could you please tell me how can I split the data and further process with Seurat or Scanpy? Or any other alternative way to analyze the data? Thank you!

I am expecting to get two datasets (WT and KO) which I can use for further processing with Seurat or Scanpy.

Comment: Seurat has a vignette for hto de-multiplexing, using HTODemux function. [the vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/hashing_vignette.html)